# React/Flux: Storing Important Params During Route Changes

Tags: routes, reactjs, url-routing, react-router, reactjs-flux

Tools: React 0.14.0, React-Router 1.0.0, Vanilla Flux

Because of "back-button" event handling - **I'm trying to use routing to keep important ids for rendering(such as `currentThreadID`).**

e.g. -  `/threads/:currentThreadID`

**Problem: Because multiple components depend on the currentThreadID I'm trying to grab params and add them to a store as a route is opened. The problem is I can't find where in my program I should be grabbing current location.**

For example I have this route

```
<Route path='/' component={Main}>
  <Route path='home' component={Home} >
    <Route path='threads' component={Thread} >
      <Route path=':currentThreadID' component={ThreadList} />  
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path='login' component={Login} />
</Route>
```

When I enter `ThreadList` I'm trying to get the param and add it to the 
store so that other components will have access to it.

**ThreadList.js**

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    var { threadID } = this.props.params
    ThreadActionCreators.setCurrentThread(threadID);
},
```

Trying to set that current ID is causing a conflict with the Dispatcher 
**"Error: Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch."**

I believe that is because of conflict with React-Router(all my other dispatches were already finished.)

**Question:
  Am I trying to disburse the "currentThreadID" state correctly? If so, where do I call the action to store the param in my stores?**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used react router in a while, but I think you can set up an action dispatch in the callback provided to Router.run to dispatch a route change action. You can then set up your store to grab the ID from the route param on the appropriate route change.

I would recommend taking a look at Redux though, it's an improvement upon the Flux architecture and redux-router has actions built in for this kind of thing.

Comment: This was a start... but I couldn't find a good example( and a lot has changed in the past year that makes it even harder to tell)